# How to `read_edgelist` of networkx set default custom weight?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm using networkx to read edges from file.
My data likes:

```
1 2
1 3
2 4
```

How to set custom weight when read from above data? I want to my data likes:

```
1 2 1.0
1 3 1.0
2 4 1.0
```

or weight may be *other value* which can be chose without weight in original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a weighted edge list while reading the file into a nested list, and then feed the weighted edges into a graph with [`add_weighted_edges_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_weighted_edges_from.html):

```
weight = 1
edges = [[*map(int,line.split()), weight] for line in open("file.txt")]
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)
G.edges(data=True)
# EdgeDataView([(1, 2, {'weight': 1}), (1, 3, {'weight': 1}), (2, 4, {'weight': 1})])
```